# How to get data for missing weeks in Summarised data

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables stores_data and financial_week as shown below. Stores data is a summarised data across multiple attributes. My task is to generate data for all the weeks present in the second table, if data is missing, the quantity should be listed as 0.

```
create table stores_data
(
    store string
    ,supplier string
    ,category string
    ,qty int
    ,financial_week int
);

create table financial_week(
    financial_week int
);

insert into stores_data values('The Ponds','Bega','Snacks',50,20211);
insert into stores_data values('The Ponds','Bega','Drinks',50,20211);
insert into stores_data values('The Ponds','Bega','Snacks',100,20212);
insert into stores_data values('Strathfield','Bega','Snacks',50,20213);
insert into stores_data values('Parramatta','Bega','Drinks',110,20214);


insert into financial_week values(20211);
insert into financial_week values(20212);
insert into financial_week values(20213);
insert into financial_week values(20214);
```

Expected Result set is this -

[image]

I have done cross join but after that I am not clearly sure how to proceed with getting missing weeks.

Here is the query I used so far but not seeing the null values to which I can put a logic in -

```
select *
from (
    select sd.*
    from stores_data sd
        cross join financial_week fw
)inr
    left join stores_data sd
        on sd.financial_week = inr.financial_week
order by inr.store,inr.supplier,inr.category,inr.financial_week
```

Comment: Show your cross join and what you got

Comment: @VKarthik . . . Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: `varchar` in BigQuery?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and then `left join` to bring in the values:

```
select ssc.store, ssc.supplier, ssc.category, fw.financial_week,
       coalesce(sd.quantity, 0)
from (select distinct store, supplier, category
      from stores_data
     ) ssc cross join
     financial_week fw left join
     stores_data sd
     on sd.store = ssc.store and sd.supplier = ssc.supplier and
        sd.category = ssc.category and
        sd.financial_week = fw.financial_week
order by ssc.store, ssc.supplier, ssc.category, fw.financial_week;
```

Note that the first part of the `cross join` generates all (distinct) combinations of `store`, `supplier`, and `category`.  The final `join` conditions use all the columns from the `cross join`ed tables.

Comment: Thank you so much @Gordon . I have about twenty odd dimensions grouped. Would this still be performance efficient? We are using bigquery. I have edited the question.

Comment: @VKarthik . . . That should be fine.